# Enabling an App to connect to the Internet

Tags: cordova, internet-connection

How do you make an app built using PhoneGap to connect to the Internet? I have tried to insert:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in the `config.xml` file but I still get a `No Connection` message. Any advice please?

Comment: you need to provide more/detailed information? Provide information such as phonegap version, Android/IOS/Windows version. Where are you testing your app emulator/actual device? How are you testing your app?

Answer (score 0):

Not very Clear Question. However, If you are testing in a mobile device which is already connected to internet you don't need anything extra for it. Rest things I can not say without knowing what are you doing actually.

Comment: Thank you anupam. Here is the link to the question with all the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203432/enable-android-app-to-connect-to-the-internet