# Enable Android App to Connect to the Internet

Tags: php, android, cordova

I have created a simple app using Phohegap to retrieve few records frm a remote database using the following index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf&minus;8" type="text/javascript">
function connect(e)
{
    var term= {button:e};
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://dubaisinan.host22.com/reply.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:term,
        dataType:'json',
        error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
            alert("No Connection");},
        timeout:60000,
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html("");
                for(var i in data){
                    $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
                }
            }
        });     
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><b>My Students</b></center>
<center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="showStudents" /></center>
<center><b>Results</b></center>
<ul data-role="listview" id="result"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following reply.php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $link = mysql_connect('host_name', 'user-name', 'password');
    if (!$link) 
    {
        $myStudents[] = "No";
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("a2808249_db1",$link);  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Students",$link);  

    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
        $myStudents[] = $myrow[1];
    }
    print json_encode($myStudents);
 ?>
```

It works fine on my laptop but when I build it using Phonegap and download the apk file on my Note 3 device, I receive the message "No Connection". It seems that the app is not able to connect to the Internet. The device has Internet connection.

Any help please?
Sinan

Comment: Do you have the internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: What does `strError` say?

Comment: strError says "No Connection". Here is my config.xml:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    version   = "1.0.0">
<access origin="*" />
<name>PhoneGap Build Application</name>
<description>
A simple PhoneGap Build application.
</description>
<author href="https://example.com" email="you@example.com">
Your Name
</author>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
</widget>

Comment: I have added <access origin="*" /> to the xml file but it did not work.

Comment: `Do you have the internet permission in your manifest file?`. Please answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

Also you said you want to retrieve, so this should be a GET call , not POST.

Also use `<!DOCTYPE html>` (proper coding standard)

Edit : Example GET call

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://abcd.com",
                headers: {
                    "X-API-KEY": "2b9asdedqedqxdqd7956e6f7a",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                type: "GET",
                data: fromDatan,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }
                });
```

**EDIT : This is a sample code which can POST to a test server**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function greeter() {

          var accx = 5;
          var accy = 6;
          var accz = 7;


                var output = [];
                output[0] = {
                        name: "Accel_X",
                        value: accx.toString(), // retrieve x
                    };
                    output[1] = {
                        name: "Accel_Y",
                        value: accy.toString(), // retrieve y
                    };
                    output[2] = {
                        name: "Accel_Z",
                        value: accz.toString() // retrieve z
                    };


                var fromData = {};
                fromData.output = output;

                var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                alert(fromDatan);


                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",
                    type: "POST",

                    data: fromDatan,

                    dataType: "JSON",

                    success: function(fromDatan, status, jqXHR) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                    },

                    error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    }

                    /*
                    error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
            alert("No Connection");},
        timeout:60000,
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html("");
                for(var i in data){
                    $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
                }
            }*/
                });
                return false;
            }
            //-->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="greeter();">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried with your url, not working. However will let you know if I can

Comment: Thanks anupam. Added <!DOCTYPE html> and the first script line only. The second gives me a syntax error on "var term= {button:e};". Changed the POST into GET. I still get "No Connection" on the device. It works fine on the laptop. Any more suggestions please?

Comment: You are assigning a button in variable? I don't have any idea regarding this.

Comment: Thanks anupam_on. Any help from others?

Comment: Just printed strError and it shows on the device: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: `Also you said you want to retrieve, so this should be a GET call , not POST.`. No. That has nothing to do with retrieving or sending. POST will be ok. Moreover the problem here is thst it does not connect first.

Comment: Changing POST to GET was suggested to me. As I mentioned, strError says: **"SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"**. What does this message mean?